# ArcMap sql server query not working in labeling

Tags: arcgis-desktop, labeling, sql, windows-10, dynamic-segmentation

We have a computer that just upgraded to windows ten. This is the only computer on windows 10. The arcmap version and drivers for ODBC and sql seem to all match up. We are dynamically segmenting to tables on multiple sql servers. On one particular sql server using the sql query in the labels tab doesn't seem to work on one of our sql servers. Can't seem to figure this out. Any ideas?

These are the steps to the sql query options for those who haven't used it.

right click on layer > layer properties > labels tab > method: define classes and label each class > sql query

1. arcmap version 10.3.0.4322
2. the data is coming from a sql server
3. It is being accessed by route event layer (dynamic segmentation).
4. example query. (Status = 2  AND Type = 'AA'  AND current = 1)

this works on one sql server but not on another.

Comment: You need to provide more information about the ArcGIS version being used, where your data come from, how is it accessed in ArcMap, the SQL query itself etc

Comment: 1. arcmap version 10.3.0.4322
2. the data is coming from a sql server
3. It is being accessed by route event layer (dynamic segmentation).
4. example query. (Status = 2  AND Job_Type = 'PR'  AND current = 1)

this works on one sql server but not on another.